# Using LoopTools to flatten quads and N-gons: Can I lock the position of one vertex point?

Tags: mesh, vertices, geometry, retopology

Hello I'm new here and hope someone can help me.

So I have this quad and I need it to be perfectly flat. I discovered the addon LoopTools and using it to flatten ("best fit") works pretty great.

The problem: One vertex point has to keep it's exact position. Only the other 3 verticies should change their position to make the whole shape flat. How do I do that?
**Can I lock the position of one point?**

Hiding doesn't seem to work because for the whole shape to become flat the point needs to be considered.

(Sorry, english isn't my native language. I hope it's not confusing!)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think there is a way to lock a vertex. You can lock an axis in the tool options at the bottom left menu in the viewport, but in the worst case this can result in the face not being flattened at all. A workaround could be to select that vertex, duplicate it with Shift+D and immediately right-click so that it stays in its original position. Then select the face, flatten it and afterwards move it with G and hold Ctrl to snap it to the duplicated vertex (make sure _Vertex_ is selected in the snapping options). Afterwards delete or merge the extra vertex.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the cursor on that one vertex you want to preserve
[image]
And then flatten the face
[image]
Then with that vertex selected as the active element and 'Active element' as the transformation pivot point, move the sellecetion to the cursor with the offset
[image]
It will move the entire face so that the active vertex is on the cursor without rotating it, which is the same result as what you want.

You are not gonna be able to flatten quads in a curved surface like that if you do this tho. This face will be flat but it will mess the other faces around it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten a region to its mean normal, leaving a vertex in place, you can:

- set the Transform Orientation to 'Normal',
- set the Pivot Point to 'Active Element'
- ensure your static vertex is active,
- and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

Or, you can use a Custom Orientation.. I have 'Create Custom Orientation' (the little '**+**' in the Transform Orientations dropdown) as a Quick Menu item, because I use it all the time. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> gives the same result.

[image]